# Is there a plugin that allows a user of your site to get an email from you with an attachment?

Tags: plugins, attachments, email

I was wondering if there was a plugin that could do the following:

1. user goes to page on wordpress site
2. user fills out their email address
3. Clicks Email Form button
4. user gets an email from my preconfigured email address via the plug with an attachment I have on my wordpress server somewhere, and some text explaining how to fill out the form or something.

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I'm looking for - do I place the PHP code in the functions.php of the theme I'm using? In this case, i'm using a Genesis child theme.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );` to send emails with attachments.

So all you need is a simple form

```
<form name="email-att" id="email-att" method="POST" action="">
Enter your emial: <br />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email"/><br />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="email-att"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

and to process it

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "email-att"){
   if (is_email($_POST['email'])){
        $to = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = "email subject line";
        $message = "email message body";
        $attachments = array('http://full_url_to_file.zip');
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, '', $attachments );
        echo 'mail sent! check your email';
    }else{
        echo 'Please enter a valid email address ';
    }
}
?>
```