# Using wp_mail with attachments but no attachments received

Tags: wp-mail

I have been looking at multiple examples including [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11480/is-there-a-plugin-that-allows-a-user-of-your-site-to-get-an-email-from-you-with).

I get the email no problem but there are no attachments. Am I missing the content/type of file type? All the examples I've seen uses only text/html as the content type.

Here's what I have (added upon Stephen's request)

```
if( isset( $_POST['to'] ) && isset( $_POST['from'] ) ) {
global $wpdb;

$to = $_POST['to'];
$from = $_POST['from']; 
$name = get_bloginfo('name');
$attachment = $_POST['file'];
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: multipart/mixed; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $from . '>' . "\r\n";   
$subject = 'Send to Kindle';
$msg = 'Yay! Your book has <a href="http://yahoo.com">arrived</a>';

$mail_attachment = array( $attachment );
wp_mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers, $mail_attachment);
echo 'Email sent';
} else {
echo 'Email not sent';
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code regarding what you've tried?

Comment: Hi Stephen, just updated the post with the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `$attachment` argument for `wp_mail` takes a file (or array of files) - but the file path has to be fully specified. For example:

```
<?php
   $attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/file_to_attach.zip');
   $headers = 'From: My Name <myname@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";
   wp_mail('test@test.com', 'subject', 'message', $headers, $attachments);
?>
```

([see Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail)). It seems that your `$_POST['file']` is probably not specifying the full path.

The attachment has to a **file path**, not an url. The following worked for me:

```
$to = $_POST['to'];
$from = $_POST['from']; 
$name = get_bloginfo('name');

$headers = 'From: My Name <myname@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";

$subject = 'Send to Kindle';

$msg = 'Yay! Your book has <a href="http://yahoo.com">arrived</a>';

$mail_attachment = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/uploads/2012/03/image.png');   

wp_mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers, $mail_attachment);
```

**Note:** I changed the `headers` attribute too. I'm not entirely sure what you're example was trying to do, but it meant the message of the email was not visible on some email clients.

Comment: Thank you Stephen for following up... ok `$_Post['file']` is actually a URL to the file and I have confirmed the URL is correct. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Nope, see updated answer :)

Comment: That means I can't have them send an attachment that is hosted elsewhere e.g. Amazon S3? I was afraid of that. I'm just trying to give people the option to email a PDF to Kindle directly from a web page. Anyhow I'll try this later and report back.

Comment: You could read the remote file, then attach it? There's an [example here](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#105661). Exactly how you can do it / best practise would be a question for SO.

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen I tried your solution and it did work. Now... I have to figure out how to send attachment hosted elsewhere. Thanks for the pointer where to look!